# Create instance of XAML based class from code while preserving XAML binding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, code-behind

An odd question here. Al ittle bit of pre-history. I am using Xamarin cross-platfrom and there are certain limitations in terms of creating interfaces and derived classes for Pages.

I have a `XAML` based page class, which I wish to use to wrap my `Pages`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NavigationPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.UI.View.ExtendedNavigationPage"
                BarTextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
                BarBackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}">
</NavigationPage>
```

and its code behind:

```
public partial class ExtendedNavigationPage
{
    public ExtendedNavigationPage(Xamarin.Forms.Page root)
        :base(root)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ExtendedNavigationPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

Finally, I create instance like this:

```
ExtendedNavigationPage NavigationPage = new ExtendedNavigationPage(new RootPage());
```

So what I need to do is create an instance of my class in code and not in `XAML`. Why? Because I cannot pass my inner `Page` object into my custom `ExtendedNavigationPage` via `XAML`.

But once I do that, my bindings do not work and I have a feeling that `XAML` code is not even used during my object creation process. I guess I am missing some understanding of how `XAML` based controls are initialized.

> How can I create instance of `XAML` class from code and preserve my
>   `XAML` unique bindings and features of the `NavigationPage`?

Comment: have you tried to set the bindingcontext before calling `InitializeComponent`?